# Changing AA batteries for rechargeable Li batteries

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated

I want to change 2 AA batteries in series for rechargeable batteries. The specs of the device are the following:

-Input Vcc: 1.8-3.3V (It seems to support 3.5, not sure if it can be an issue)

-Consumption: Sleep 5uA, running 1mA, transmitting 450mA.

The device runs around 10 times per day, the running mode lasts for around 3 seconds each. I expect it to work for about a month before having to recharge it, can anyone suggest me a way to find this out or a straight forward battery?

Comment: Two AA batteries in parallel would range from about 1.55 when fresh, down to maybe 1 or 0.8 when fully discharged. Maybe you meant two AA in series?

Comment: Edited, got picked by the looks of em being side by side. Thanks

Comment: Standard Lithium Ion and Lithium polymer batteries range from 4.2V down to around 3.5V (in low-drain applications like yours). So that won't work. The easiest rechargeable solution would be to just use two AA NiMH batteries. But maybe you could use one Lithium Iron phosphate cell.